# Use javascript file in a different project

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript (which uses files from it's own project) file that I need to use in a different project without copy the code.
How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: I have a glass of water, I need to have water in another glass

Comment: put them on a cdn, i.e. shared network

Answer (score 0):

Well... You *could* install [Bower](http://bower.io/), upload your file to your own [repository](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/) on [GitHub](https://github.com/) and then use bower to include them as a dependancy for your project.

Setting up (assuming you have [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) already installed)

```
npm install -g bower
cd /path/to/project-A
bower init
bower install <link to your gist/repo> --save
cd /path/to/project-B
bower init
bower install <link to your gist/repo> --save
```

And then in the future, if you upload changes to your repo/gist (and the link has not changed...)

```
cd /path/to/project
bower update
```

EDIT: That or you have a remotely hosted version of this file that you directly link to, I guess...? Kinda sucks though, could wreck a live project from a dodgy edit that way

Comment: Using bower to copy the file still copies it though

Comment: Well yea whatever you do, unless all projects are on the same server and you link to the exact same file, it is going to end with 2 copies of the file. But at least this way the file's version is managed by a package manager, and you can edit it once on github and just do `bower update` to update in project. EDIT: that or you have a remotely hosted version of this file that you directly link to, I guess...?